# Is "lays important groundwork" appropriate usage

Tags: grammar, conjugation

As in: "My project lays important groundwork for a future project."

Is my usage of 'lays' correct?  I'm not sure why I'm hung up on this, it just doesn't sound correct to me.

Comment: *"My project lays* ***down*** *important groundwork for a future project."* Sometimes the "down" can be omitted, but I don't think your example is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence requires, in my opinion, the definite article as in:

> My project lays **the** important groundwork for a future project

You could omit *important* or experiment substituting it with other adjectives such as *essential*, to see if the sentence has greater impact and flows more naturally.

> My project lays the (essential) groundwork for a future project

Edit
I double-checked with Google books and *[lays the groundwork](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lays%20the%20groundwork%22&num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=fEl0U4DvL8P20gWd34GIAg&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=653)* has 760,000 results while *lays groundwork* has "only" 2,790 results.

Comment: Fascinating cross reference.  Thanks @Mari-Lou A.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly disagree with many of the points made by 1) F.E. 2) Guilherme Oderdenge and 3) Tucker. (Preceding asterisks indicate non-standard/non-idiomatic usages or constructions):

> My project lays important groundwork for a future project. [Your original wording.]

More idiomatic:

> My project lays **some** important groundwork for a future project.

1)

> *My project lays down important groundwork for a future project.

2)

> My project establishes [some] important groundwork for a future project.
>
> *My project establishes an important groundwork for a future project.

Guilherme's own prose also falls significantly short of the standard one would expect from  a native speaker.

3)

There is no tense incompatibility. The project lays the groundwork [in the present] for a project that will take place in the future.

---

Incidentally, there are quite a few possible alternatives to 'lays the groundwork':

*sets the stage, prepares the way/ground, establishes/comprises the basis/foundation,* and *sets the framework* all come to mind.

Answer (score -3):

There's a tense incompatibility.

The word **[lays](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lay)** is a verb in the 3rd person present tense. Your sentence is in the future tense, that is why it sounds wrong.

Consider:

> My project will lay important groundwork for a future project.